# slice reducer for key "pageName" returned undefined during initialization

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-reducers

I am creating redux app using createSlice(), but get the error:

> Error: The slice reducer for key "pageName" returned undefined during
> initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you
> must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be
> undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can
> use null instead of undefined.

Here is the minimal example for this error.

pageNameSlice.js:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const pageNameSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'pageName',
    initalState: "",
    // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
    reducers: {
      setPageName: (state, newName) => {
          state.pageName = newName
      }
    }
});

export default pageNameSlice.reducer;
```

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import pageNameReducer from '../features/pageNameSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    pageName: pageNameReducer
  },
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo there - `initalState` should be `initialState`. (This is more common than you might think ^^)

Comment: cannot believe this is the cause :)

Comment: Don't feel bad @EzyHoo. I had the exact same typo and didn't spot it until I got here.